# Get checked treeview children to arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, treeview

Please could someone help me to get checked children of a treeview to an arraylist in c#

Comment: I put [Get checked treeview childs c#](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Get+checked+treeview+childs+c%23&oq=Get+checked+treeview+childs+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.4785j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into google and got a good starting point... you should do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the ArrayList with recursion, something like that

```
    // Add Node checked children into ArrayList
    private static void AddCheckedNodes(TreeNode node, ArrayList list) {
      if (node.Checked)
        list.Add(node);

      for (int i = 0; i < node.Nodes.Count; ++i)
        AddCheckedNodes(node.Nodes[i], list);
    }

    // Add TreeView checked nodes into ArrayList
    public static void AddCheckedNodes(TreeView value, ArrayList list) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, list))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

      for (int i = 0; i < value.Nodes.Count; ++i) 
        AddCheckedNodes(value.Nodes[i], list);
    }

   ...

   AddCheckedNodes(myTreeView, myArrayList);
```

P.S. ArrayList is an obsolete class, List will be better